# Tooltip isn't showing when position is set

Tags: jquery, position, jquery-ui-tooltip

I'm using jQuery UI to show tooltip with image and description. I want change position of tooltip. But when I use "position" option tooltip doesn't show. Code is below.

Without positionig:

```
$( "#vip" )
  .tooltip({ content: '<img src="img/sale/taneczna.jpg" /> Description of image'})
```

with:

```
$( "#vip" )
  .tooltip({ content: '<img src="img/sale/taneczna.jpg" /> ( mieści ok. 30 osób)', 
  position: { my: "top right", at: "right center" }})
```

How to change tooltip position?

Comment: This works for me. Do you have an element with the vip id? make sure that element has a title attribute

Comment: @heymega 

Yes, I have that element. If I haven't it will not work at all. It's only stop working when I add "position" atribute.

Comment: please show what you done so far in a fiddle.